# XCODE: error opening input file '/Users/name/Desktop/test/appname/node_modules/react-native-compressor/ios/Video/Compressor-Bridging-Header.h'

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, xcode, react-native

I have a problem when I run my project in XCode.
I just installed the package `react-native-compressor` by following the [installation instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compressor)
And when I run my project in XCode, I have this problem:

```
<unknown>:0: error: error opening input file '/Users/name/Desktop/test/appname/node_modules/react-native-compressor/ios/Video/Compressor-Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)
```

This file exists, and contain exactly what contains in this url: https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor/blob/master/ios/Video/VideoCompressor.h

Answer (score 0):

This Path might be incorrect as After `/Users/` it says `name` while there should be an account name of macbook profile that is currently logged in.

Just validate your path like that

[image]

Comment: sorry, I changed my name to "name" because I want to stay in the anonyma...

Comment: can you manually verify the path, the error is displaying that there is issue with the path

Comment: Yes, my path is true. I deleted my derived data and now I get another error: `Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code`... too weird

Comment: That's bridging file For ObjC in Xcode, in Xcode Project go to build settings -> objective-c bridging header and clear path and add bridging file again

Comment: What do you mean by "and add bridging file again" ?

Comment: It's about adding path of the bridging file if you have one in your xcode project

Comment: Yes I have, but his file is empty...